# Iterate through an XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

My XML file looks like below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:queryBroadcastDetailResponse xmlns:ns="http://com/everbridge/ws3">
      <ns:return type="com.nnn.api.messaging.BroadcastDetailResponse">
        <ns:detailBeans type="com.nnn.api.messaging.BroadcastDetailBean">
          <ns:memberBeans type="com.nnn.api.messaging.MessagingMemberInfoBean">
            <ns:contactInfoBeans type="com.nnn.api.messaging.ContactInfoBean">
              <ns:callResult>E-Mail Not Confirmed</ns:callResult>
              <ns:contactPath>john.doe@website.com</ns:contactPath>
            </ns:contactInfoBeans>
            <ns:firstName>John</ns:firstName>
            <ns:lastName>Doe</ns:lastName>
          </ns:memberBeans>
          <ns:memberBeans type="com.nnn.api.messaging.MessagingMemberInfoBean">
            <ns:contactInfoBeans type="com.nnn.api.messaging.ContactInfoBean">
              <ns:callResult>E-Mail Not Confirmed</ns:callResult>
              <ns:contactPath>jane.doe@website.com</ns:contactPath>
            </ns:contactInfoBeans>
            <ns:firstName>Jane</ns:firstName>
            <ns:lastName>Doe</ns:lastName>
          </ns:memberBeans>
          <ns:messageBean type="com.nnn.api.messaging.MessageBean">
            <ns:broadcastId>123456</ns:broadcastId>
            <ns:duration>20</ns:duration>
            <ns:language>English (US)</ns:language>
          </ns:messageBean>
          <ns:totalConfirmed>0</ns:totalConfirmed>
          <ns:totalUnconfirmed>16</ns:totalUnconfirmed>
        </ns:detailBeans>
        <ns:errors xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
        <ns:status>SUCCESS</ns:status>
        <ns:statusMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
      </ns:return>
    </ns:queryBroadcastDetailResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And I am trying to get the data which is kept inside the `<ns:memberBeans>`, like I need the `callResult`, `contactPath`, `firstName`, `lastName` from each memberBeans (there are tons of them).

I believe I've to use the inbuilt SimpleXML class for this, but I am unable to actually extract the content from it. I have read a bunch of tutorials for this only and read similar answers on Stackoverflow, but they have been to no avail to me till now.

Comment: Can you also include your PHP code so far?

Comment: This is a wsdl best consumed with [soapclient()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)

Comment: @SeanBright I don't have much right now, I've tried a bunch of things and they all were fundamentally wrong. I know I need to start by `$data = $items->soapenv->children('http://com/everbridge/ws3')` and then I need to use foreach loops, however I'm not sure how can I select the individual <ns> inside `<ns:contactInfoBeans>`. Something like `foreach ($data as $data->ns->ns->ns->ns)` will probably not work...

Comment: @DigitalChris Umm, what is that?

Comment: It's a link; read it ;). This might also help:http://devzone.zend.com/2202/php-and-soap-first-steps/ and searching wsdl, soap, php soap-based web service

Comment: Yes, reading through that only. Actually I am using everbridge.com for some notification system for my application and I need to interpret and receive data which comes in this form. I'm still confused how can I extract the data values from it?